# What should I do so that "nan" doesn't show up in console?

Tags: c++, nan

My teacher gave this homework. Basically I have two numbers, a and b. I have to show to console [answer of this formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWf82.png) for every 'a' number added h=(b-a)/10 but in console I see just nan. How can I solve this error?
My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
double s(double x){
    long f = 1;
    long double anw=1;
    for(int k=1;k<=100;k++){
        f=k*f;
         anw=((pow((x-1),k)*pow(log(3),k))/f)+anw;
    }
    return anw;
}
int main(){
    double a=0.2, b=0.8, h;
    h=(b-a)/10;
    for(double x=a; x<=b ;x+=h){
        cout<<"s(x)="<<s(x)<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sorry for my bad English!

Comment: Unrelated, but `math.h` is a C header which strictly speaking does not exist in C++. The equivalent C++ header is `cmath`.

Comment: @Brian -- strictly speaking, the C headers do exist in C++. Always have and always will. Yes, folks usually should use the `cxxx` versions, but the C versions work just fine if you don't mind polluting the global namespace.

Comment: @PeteBecker Ah, so you're right. They do exist as a deprecated feature under [depr.c.headers]. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a signed integer overflow in `f=k*f;` so I suggest that you make `f` a `double`:

```
double s(double x){
    double f = 1;              // double
    long double anw=1;
    for(int k=1;k<=100;k++){
        f = k * f;             // or else you get a signed integer overflow here
        // f *= k;             // a simpler way of writing the above
        anw=((pow((x-1),k)*pow(log(3),k))/f)+anw;
    }
    return anw;
}
```

Another note: Include the C++ header `cmath` instead of the C header `math.h`.